# Google Analytics - dynamic segment with conditions api

Tags: google-analytics, segment, segments

I have a segment in GA that does the following....

It is a conditional segment

```
Filter Sessions
Exclude

Network Domain - exactly Matched - unknown.unknown
AND
medium - exactly matches - (none)
AND
Country/Territory - matches regex - united\ states|ireland
AND
Transactions - Per Session = 0
```

This works as I want in the user interface
(I know this is a little bit over the top, but we are getting hit by non identifiable traffic at the moment and until i can filter it out this is what i need to use)

I also have a number of rpeorts that run off the api that I would like to add this segment to.

I have written the following dynamic segment but it doesnt properly work

```
sessions::condition::ga:networkdomain!~unknown\.unknown;ga:medium!~\(none\);ga:country!~united states|ireland|australia;perSession::ga:transactions>0
```

It seems to be excluding each one individually and not as a condition

Has anyone had anyluck with an exclusion segment over the api with conditions, could you give me some pointers

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a missing feature in GA API: https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=414